# How can I export a blender file into fbx and import it to unity so it will look and work the same way?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, import, export, blender

I have a model in blender with texturas, animations and multiple objects. When I put the blend file in the unity project it works just fine, but when I export it as fbx and import it into unity everything is completely messed up. The texturas mess up, the animations donwt wotk or only one of them and parts of the model apear rotated and not placed at their places. I tried every export and import settings, parented them to one empty object, changes rigging to legasy and went through all the animations to play them:

```
Animation animation = GameObject.Find("Head").GetComponent<Animation>();
         animation.Play();
         foreach (AnimationState state in animation)
         {
             animation.Play(state.name);
             Debug.Log(state.name);
         }
```

but still nothing works and everything is completely messed up..What do I do wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can really search 10000s of pages on this; it may help you

Comment: I tried so many things and read so many tutorials..and every export it looks messed up in some way..Please can You or someone please tell me what can be the reason for that.. @Joe blow

Comment: Show us your fbx export page from blender , which options you chose ?

Comment: I tried the default once, I also tried the apply  transform and other checkings but nothing worked fine.. @MiladQasemi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding empty object to your blender hierarchy I use plain axes and then export again. Just add it no need to reorganize your structure. This happens for axys orientation, is different across blender and unity.

BTW: why are you exporting using fbx? You can drag and drop any blender file into unity assets folder, ready for using.